# Fail to enable mod_rewrite on my apache server

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This is how my apache httpd file looks like:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

<Directory / >
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride ALL
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

Now i try to execute this simple mod rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^product-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?id=$1
```

This rewrite should happen when i press this link:

```
 <a href="product-91.html">Press me</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you put your rewrite rule in the apache config you will need a leading / after the ^(not needed for htaccess).  Try the rule with out ^ to see if it matches.  I have also had some servers/vhosts where I needed to add RewriteBase rewrite would work.

Comment: That has worked. very strange..why did the ^ interfer? or was it the RewriteBAse that did the job

Comment: If you have time you might want to try playing around with both.  ^ is start of string.  You can try replacing ^ with ^/ to see if that works.